# Static networking not working with Squeeze KVM guest

Tags: networking, debian, kvm-virtualization

I just installed Debian Squeeze as guest on an Ubuntu Server KVM host with bridged networking. I have other Ubuntu Server guests running on the same host, all the VM use static IPs. When I use DHCP, the Squeeze VM has networking working properly, but when I give it a static IP, I can no longer ping Google, or my public IP. However, I can still ping the other VM with static IPs. What could be causing this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following are possible solutions (this data is normally provided by DHCP).

- Ensure your DNS server(s) are specified in `/etc/resolv.conf`.
- Ensure your default route is defined and specifies your router.  `netstat -r` should list your routes.

It is possible to specify fixed IP addresses using DHCP.  This can be done by ID, MAC address, or name.  Particulars on how do do so depends on your DHCP server.   KVM is likely using `dnsmasq` which may read `/etc/ethers` when it start up.

Comment: Ok. It seems like specifying the gateway for eth0 in my /etc/network/interfaces file did not set a default route for that interface. Seems strange. under ubuntu server, it works perfectly well. Is this a normal behaviour for Debian Squeeze ?

Comment: I moved to Ubuntu quite a while ago.  They have moved to network manager.  Directions for getting old behaviour back are at http://wiki.debian.org/NetworkManager#Enabling_Interface_Management.